# Merge two AutoHotkey scripts

Tags: autohotkey

I have two functioning scripts. When I combine them, the second doesn't function or causes an error on script 1.

Script 1 = A simple menu script I want to assign hotkeys to.
Script 2 = A small launcher script from a user named Tertius in AutoHotkey forum.

See the codes merged: http://pastebin.com/uuaDKNXu

See Keywords.ini needed in script 2: http://pastebin.com/LtybdSxG

See Script 1: http://pastebin.com/Wf3bMWd4

See Script 2: http://pastebin.com/sFjVAGqE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that each script has an auto-execute section, but only the first section is being processed. With autohotkey, the auto-execute section ends the first time the `return` keyword or a hotkey label like `$Tab::` is processed.

I made [a new pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vNVz8zQ9) that turns the auto-execute section from the second script into a function, and then calls it with GoSub.

I created the function by putting this line at the start of script 1 (line 102 in the linked script):

```
popupMenuScriptStartup:
```

Then we call this function on line 10 of the script:

```
GoSub popupMenuScriptStartup
```

Comment: Thanks Ranomore, your corrections solved the problem and the merged script is fully functional now. Great explanation too!

Answer (score 0):

I [found](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic57125.html) a couple of alternative methods for using multiple AHK scripts: [#include](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm) and [Run](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm)

- If the second file is a collection of methods/functions, you can simply include it by using

  ```
  #include FullPathToFile.ahk
  ```

  at the top of your file. You can then call all your methods from the second script in the first as needed.
- If the second file is a standalone script that includes initialization that needs to be run as part of the startup, you could just `Run` run the second script from the first. You'd also want to close it when the first script exits:

  ```
  Run FullPathToSecondScript.ahk,,, pidToCloseOnExit
  ...
  WinClose, ahk_pid, pidToCloseOnExit
  Exit App
  ```

Because of the nature of the script you're trying to add, I don't think the first option would work for you.